# refresh datagridview after insert or update or delete without selecting new sql query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I just want to clarify, can i refresh datagridview after insert or update or delete without selecting new sql query again ?
i have googled it, and still have no idea to do it.

here's my code

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        employee();
    }

    public void employee()
    {
        DataTable dtclubroom = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, myConnection);
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            dtclubroom.Clear();
            command.Connection = myConnection;
            command.CommandText = "Select * from employee ";
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(dtclubroom);  
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dtclubroom;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand();
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            command2.CommandText = "insert into employee (name,id) values (@name,@id)";
            command2.Connection = myConnection;
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name","Leon");
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "002");
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception  exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        employee() //<- refresh datagridview
    }
```

`Button 4` is to load data, and `button 5` inserting data also load data. is there a way refresh datagridview without calling `employee()` method again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in couple of ways.

1. Add the newly inserted record to your datatable (you need to use a global datatable variable for this) and refresh your `Grid View` using this datatable.
2. You can add the newly inserted record directly to the `Grid View`

You can follow these techniques also for **DELETE** and **UPDATE**

Here is the implementation of idea #1 for your existing code :

```
DataTable dtclubroom = new DataTable();

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    employee();
}

public void employee()
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, myConnection);
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        dtclubroom.Clear();
        command.Connection = myConnection;
        command.CommandText = "Select * from employee ";
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(dtclubroom);  
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dtclubroom;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand();
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        command2.CommandText = "insert into employee (name,id) values (@name,@id)";
        command2.Connection = myConnection;
        command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name","Leon");
        command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "002");
        command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataRow dr = dtclubroom.NewRow();
        dr["name"] = "Leon";
        dr["id"] = "002";
        dtclubroom.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    catch (Exception  exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }

    dataGridView2.DataSource = dtclubroom; //<- refresh datagridview
}
```

Look that the datatable declaration is moved up and you need to place it in top of your class :

```
DataTable dtclubroom = new DataTable();
```

Nothing else need to be global.

Comment: how ?, still won't work, until i declare datatable as global and also the sqladapter as global. but the datatable is duplicated. is there anyway beside declare as global because in some form there's so many data to be inserted also displayed

Comment: @chopperfield - I updated my answer, please try this. You don't need to have global `sqladapter`. BTW you don't need to write many code for your so many data, just do it once in proper place and in generalized way and use it from everywhere.

Comment: i have tried it,not working. in logic the datatable still using the select one (old). so of course it'snot updating after insert :|

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add a block! Updating the answer very soon.

Comment: well, it works but kinda fishy. since adding a row into datagridview manually. because let's say it failed during insert, but the datagrid still adding a new row :v . well it's just the flow where to put the add new row code. thanks though

Comment: @chopperfield - If it fails during insert, the row will not be added to the datatable, because it will move to Catch. Yes i just gave you the solution of your current issue and you can take it as a concept and you can implement this concept elsewhere. Please mark this answer as useful and accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: oh yeah, i forgot about the catch. haha